# Google Site Search - Filtering with PageMap attributes that contain blanks / special characters

Tags: search, google-custom-search

We're using a PageMap to provide structured data with our Html content. Part of this structured data are keywords that are displayed on the result page. Furthermore, it should also be possible to filter the results with such a keyword.

We do have keywords that contain spaces as well as special characters. So here's an excerpt of a result element returned by the XML API of the Google Site Search:

```
<PageMap>
  <DataObject type="document">
    <Attribute name="mykeywords">Computer &amp; Hobby</Attribute>
    ...
  </DataObject>
</PageMap>
```

This works perfectly for displaying the result. However, for filtering we would have to pass a query like that:

```
more:pagemap:document-mykeywords:computer___hobby
```

How can we determine the query string from the result in the XML? Simply by lowercasing the value and replacing every non word character with _? How reliable is this?

Or is it better to provide two distinct attributes in our PageMap, one for the label of the keyword and the other for the id of the keyword?